# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 942: ordinal not in range(128) SQLAlchemy (Django)

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I use SQLAlchemy query with utf-8 encode when i use run query on mysqldb i get output, but run code on python i get error  :

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 942: ordinal not in range(128)
```

query :

```
  query = """SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.ID AS 'persons_ID', p.FirstName AS 'persons_FirstName', p.LastName AS 'persons_LastName',p.NationalCode AS 'persons_NationalCode', p.CityID AS 'persons_CityID', p.Mobile AS 'persons_Mobile',p.Address AS 'persons_Address', cities_1.ID AS 'cities_1_ID', cities_1.Name AS 'cities_1_Name',cities_1.ParentID AS 'cities_1_ParentID', cities_2.ID AS 'cities_2_ID', cities_2.Name AS 'cities_2_Name',cities_2.ParentID AS 'cities_2_ParentID' , cast(@row := @row + 1 as unsigned) as 'persons_row_number' FROM Persons p LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS cities_2 ON cities_2.ID = p.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS cities_1 ON cities_1.ID = cities_2.ParentID , (select @row := 0) as init WHERE 1=1 AND p.FirstName LIKE N'{}%'""".format('رامین')
```

Conntector charset Mysql :

```
e = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://@localhost/test?charset=utf8")
```

do you  have idea for resolve ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 uses bytestrings (ASCII) strings by default, which support only Latin characters. Python 3 uses Unicode strings by default.

As I see you use some Arabic script in your query and therefore you probably get some in response. The error says, that, obviously, Python can't decode Arabic characters to ASCII. To handle Arabic (or any other non-Latin) characters you have to use unicode in Python. Note: it has nothing to do with unicode setting you provide, which affects only the database.

So your options are:

1. Switch to Python 3.
2. Stay as you are, but add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the start of your every module to enable using unicode for strings by default.
3. Use `encode`/`decode` everytime to manipulate with unicode and bytestrings, but it's the worst solution.

Comment: Yes! i test with latin work it, i need persian in query i get error,

Comment: Try number 2 from my answer, it should help.